# Preparing million rows data for visulation

Tags: mysql, database, bigdata

We want to develop a web based application that able to generate reports by using million lines of data and it is growing every second. We are using Mysql database.

We want to generate reports by using this data. That's why We need to filter data, make some calculations on it and serve it as charts, tables etc... Building charts, tables is OK, I'm asking about how to derive data.

The first way to derive report data is using native SQL queries;
But, Filtering and calculation for each report is very slow, so we will have more than 100 users that can export reports.

Second way is using Views;
We can build Views for custom calculations and views, it is an easy way to handle calculations but it is slow on queries. So filtering will slow down us.

I don't know if I can use an external tool to filter and calculate data at real time. What is the best and fast way to generate report data.

Comment: You need a proper server that's also configured well to let you use its resources - do not use default MySQL configuration. Your data scheme is going to be a huge factor here. Reports, once done, should be cached and you update the cache as the new data comes in - this is called materializing the views or materialized views. MariaDB fork of MySQL has something called Flexviews which update incrementally as the data comes in, and it's very efficient. Basically, you combine caching with optimum server and data schema configuration.

Comment: For a million (properly indexed) rows, the default set up should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Filtering at database level should be quicker than other means. As I do not have much info about your database, tables and queries, you can try modifying table schema, adding keys on the filter columns, using explain queries, change order of filter columns in where clause, pulling only the necessary columns, and so transferring the least amount of data possible from backend to front end, etc. Do whatever extra data manipulation required on client side.
Hope this helps little bit.